# How to edit specific value of a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to edit a specific value in a `CSV` file to subtract the `quantity` value with a specific `TYRE SIZE`. Here is my code:

```py
import uuid
import pyqrcode
import csv

q = str(uuid.uuid1())
print(q)

uuidcreate = pyqrcode.create(q)

uuidcreate.png('myqr'+q+'.png', scale=6)
uu = str(input('UUID:'))
uuid = uu

with open('data.csv','a')as f:
  data = csv.reader(f)
  for row in data:
        if uu in row:
            print(row)
```

the csv:

```
TYRE SIZE,BRAND,PATTERN,TT/TL,QUANTITY,UUID
135/75R14,CEAT,MILEAGE,TL,2,23e89850-ea41-11ec-bfce-68fef70199d5
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can aproach this with pandas, pandas has the readCsv comand that will return you a dataframe witch is very usefull for data manipulation.
If you want to subtract the quantity of a specific tyre size you can make something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv',sep='your csv separator')
df[df['TYRE SIZE']=='Tire Size you want to subtract']['QUANTITY']-=ammount_you_want_to_subtract
```

Edit 1:
The code would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
input_uuid = input('Insert an UUID here')
remove = input('Insert amount to remove here')

df = pd.read_csv('mycsv.csv',sep=';')
df[(df['UUID'])==input_uuid]['QUANTITY'] -= int(remove)

df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

I would recomend you make this on a jupyter notebook, it is easy to see what is hapening to the code with it

Comment: `df[df['TYRE SIZE']=='Tire Size you want to subtract']['QUANTITY']` can be `df.loc[df['TYRE SIZE']=='Tire Size you want to subtract', 'QUANTITY']]`

Comment: Also it's `pd.read_csv`